# No * candidates produce the expected contextual result type 'FloatingPointRoundRule'

Tags: swift

I get the error from the title with this code on the `return` line using Swift 3:

```
extension Double {
    /// Rounds the double to decimal places value
    mutating func roundToPlaces(_ places:Int) -> Double {
        let divisor = pow(10.0, Double(places))
        return round(self * divisor) / divisor
    }
}
```

Does someone know what does this mean ? From what I can see `round` takes a `Double` and returns a `Double`. I can't see what the issue is.

Comment: You are right. I have to specify Darwin in front of round.

Comment: Yup, or `return (self * divisor).rounded() / divisor`. Although as a side note, why is your `roundToPlaces(_:)` method `mutating`? You don't mutate anything.

Comment: Or you can also write `return (self * divisor / divisor).rounded(.awayFromZero)` Note that the `Double.round` function was introduced in Xcode 8 beta and very promptly deprecated in favor of `rounded`. And we can all understand why